# Updating date in mySql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a DATE column with dates in 2012-02-25 format. I need to update it to 12-02-25 but am not sure how to go about it?

Thanks!

Edit: After reviewing all the answers, it seems I have not been clear enough. I do not wish to change my type, nor do I wish to play with the output. I want to update the existing date column from 2012 to 12. It should be an UPDATE query if anything, I'm just not sure how to write it. Thanks for all the comments so far.

Edit 2: It seems my question did not make sense, I was not aware you could not store DATE as xx-xx-xx. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Why do you need the 12 instead of the 2012?

Comment: These dates are fetched in a javascript, which I have absolutely no understanding of, hence why I wanted to change the database itself. Thanks!

Comment: you are better of changing the `SELECT` that gets the data into javascript and use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to store date in this format `'12-02-25'` in column having `DATE` as datatype. You can store it in column having data type as `CHAR(8)` and then use following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_column = DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%y-%m-%d');
```

but better approach would be to store it in `DATE` format only and use `DATE_FORMAT` function while retrieving the data from table.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I was not aware you simply couldn't store it as xx-xx-xx. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the mysql [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to display it as you need:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(youdatecolumn, '%y-%m-%d') FROM yourtable
```

Comment: wrong answer. He wanted to updated it while it is in the database not "Select" it

Comment: @babooney it really depends of what is the intended use.  As @omesh says, there is no way to store the date differently in a `DATE` column so perhaps using the `DATE_FORMAT` could be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date-time type. Otherwise you will have some problems (sorting, relating with dates etc.)

You can change display of the date as output.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the output is not an option at the moment, it really needs to be db side if possible. date-time also wouldn't work, I don't want the time at all ;)

Comment: @Sherif: how is the column defined?  I *hope* it's "datetime" or "date" (not "varchar"!)  Nevertheless, you can always use mySQL ["DATE_FORMAT()"](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format) to interconvert between datetime and any arbitrary string format.

Comment: if you want you can do it. But its unlogical. Firstly you should use varchar format. You can store date as yy-mm-dd. (in php $date = date("y-m-d")) But i pointed out that. You'll have some problems.

Comment: I don't understand your last answer. I don't want to change it to varchar, why can't I just keep it as date? I'm aware that 2 digit years can be ambiguous, but it won't be causing problems in this case as the years stored will never be outside of the 00-69 range.

Answer (score 0):

From my [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/two-digit-years.html):

> Date values with two-digit years are ambiguous because the century is
>   unknown. Such values must be interpreted into four-digit form because
>   MySQL stores years internally using four digits.
>
> For DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP types, MySQL interprets dates
>   specified with ambiguous year values using these rules:
>
> Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
>
> Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.
>
> For YEAR, the rules are the same, with this exception: A numeric 00
>   inserted into YEAR(4) results in 0000 rather than 2000. To specify
>   zero for YEAR(4) and have it be interpreted as 2000, specify it as a
>   string '0' or '00'.
>
> Remember that these rules are only heuristics that provide reasonable
>   guesses as to what your data values mean. If the rules used by MySQL
>   do not produce the values you require, you must provide unambiguous
>   input containing four-digit year values.

Comment: Thanks, I had read that and that's why I'm ok using DATE; the dates used are starting in 2012 and I am quite certain that by the time we get to 2069, this site will be long dead haha. I don't really risk running into ambiguity issues anytime soon.

Comment: @Sherif: Well if you've read it, you would've probably understood the fact that MySQL internally stores years using four digits. So if you still want to keep your `Date` column intact, I think you probably might've to live with the four digit format. However, you might create a [`Year(2)` column] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/year.html) to sort of "hackishly" store the year

Comment: I may have misunderstood then; you cannot store it as 12? Wouldn't it then simply be interpreted internally as 2012?

Comment: @Sherif: as per the [reference docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/two-digit-years.html), that's what it seems. Read section 11.3.8 and I guess that will help you get a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

sample code try code

```
public class MyDateParser {

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String s = "2011-03-27";// or 3/27/2011

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = s.length() == 9 ? new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd") : new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = dateFormatter.parse(s);
    calendar.setTime(date);



    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

    String strss = simpleDateFormat2.format(date);
    System.out.println(strss);

}
```

}